# Could an in page table of contents and/or anchors be added to the legal pages?

Tags: feature-request, help, legal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please add deep-linking to stackexchange.com/legal sections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115006/please-add-deep-linking-to-stackexchange-com-legal-sections)

I referred to the [legal pages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/legal) occasionally already, specifically the [trademark guidance](https://stackapps.com/legal/trademark-guidance) for [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) to provide the official guidelines regarding someones app related questions or activities. (The guidance is very clear and helpful btw., thanks!)

Usually it makes sense to refer to the specific section regarding the topic at hand, see e.g. my own question [Shouldn’t the API help be consistent with the trademark guidance?](https://stackapps.com/questions/983/shouldnt-the-api-help-be-consistent-with-the-trademark-guidance), where I would have preferred to link to section *Proper Use of the Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange Name* directly rather than just citing its title.

This would be possible if major sections would have an anchor (and provide much better link context on the side). Of course, to make it easily discoverable the anchor should be surfaced somehow and an in page table of contents would likely be helpful anyway in terms of usability I'd say.

Could the legal pages be enhanced like that?