# Add anchors to the Stack Exchange terms of service sections

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, hyperlinks, terms-of-service

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Please add deep-linking to stackexchange.com/legal sections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115006/please-add-deep-linking-to-stackexchange-com-legal-sections)

I'd like to be able to directly reference a section of the [Stack Exchange Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal) (for example, when <strike>handing out candy</strike> sending a moderator message).

However, right now, there are no anchors in the Terms of Service page, and trying to reference specific sections of it is difficult.

Comment: I was just thinking about this the other day. It would be handy.

Comment: I created a post with the same request earlier: [Please add deep-linking to stackexchange.com/legal sections](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115006/please-add-deep-linking-to-stackexchange-com-legal-sections) and there's another here: [Could an in page table of contents and/or anchors be added to the legal pages?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55759/could-an-in-page-table-of-content-and-or-anchors-be-added-to-the-legal-pages) (which I didn't find at the time I created mine).  The votes are increasing for each one, so maybe now's the time?

Comment: @KevinVermeer Yes, they are all obvious dupes.  Do we want to make them dupes of this since this has the most votes?  Or vice versa?

Comment: @KevinVermeer Going by the "best question" rules, I've nominated yours as the best.  I'll close the others as dupes of that.